# No sound in World of Goo?

Tags: sound, 12.04

I installed WorldOfGooSetup.1.41.deb and it didn't work. There was a segmentation fault error (core dumped) in terminal. I fixed that with:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.* /opt/WorldOfGoo/libs32
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.* /opt/WorldOfGoo/libs64
```

That error is new for me as I have never had it before with previous releases of Ubuntu.

The game starts now but no sound effects or music is played.

I can hear music with my computer, videos, etc, so it is not a volume control problem.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 final release.

Answer (score 3):

The solution works, but changes the screen resolution when you exit the game.

To correct this check what your screen resolution is with the "monitor" tool then run

```
gksudo gedit /opt/WorldOfGooDemo/properties/config.txt
```

Change the figures for screen resolution from 800 and 600 to whatever you have and save the file.

Answer (score 3):

I find that

```
padsp /path/to/world-of-goo-binary
```

works. It puts a Pulse Audio wrapper around the w-o-g's use of the sound card.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem (no sound and wrong screen resolution in-game and after quit) on Ubuntu Mate 17.04

What I did was editing /opt/WorldOfGoo/config.txt

So first of all set this parameter values to your screen resolution because in my case it could not be detected correctly by the app itself:

      `<param name="screen_width" value="1920" />
      <param name="screen_height" value="1080" />`

Next, in this line

`<env name="SDL_AUDIODRIVER" value="auto" overwrite="true" />`

Change auto to your audio driver (see comment above this line in config) because somehow it cannot be detected by the app to so auto here results to Segmentation Fault.

`<env name="SDL_AUDIODRIVER" value="pulse" overwrite="true" />`

So the next problem was that the WorldOfGoo binary is not working properly, but the WorldOfGoo.bin64 is. I don't know what will be on 32bit systems, probably the bin32 one will work.

```
# Rename WorldOfGoo binary to something else
mv WorldOfGoo WorldOfGoo_old
# Create the shell script
nano rungoo.sh
# With the following contents
   cd /opt/WorldOfGoo
   ./WorldOfGoo.bin64
# Permit executing the script
chmod +x rungoo.sh
# Symlink it to WorldOfGoo
ln -s rungoo.sh WorldOfGoo
```

And now the menu launcher created by the installer should launch the game properly.

Answer (score 2):

hi i had this same problem and found the answer here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11802779&postcount=9.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This works but sets the resolution of the game to something in 3:4 that's really not nice on my display. Before, I could use it without sound when copying the config.txt from /opt/WorldOfGoo/properties to ~/.WorldOfGoo/config.txt and setting the Sound Server to pulseaudio with the right resolution. This doesn't work anymore. Very strange.

Comment: Works for me on 12.04.1 LTS 64 bits. Thanks! (The resolution can be changed in config.txt)

Comment: Worked for me on 12.04.1 LTS 32 bit. No issues whatsoever. Thank you!